# emacs org src output with accented characters

Tags: org-mode

When I perform

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql coding: utf-8-with-signature :results list :var did='2019-03-10' cid=77
  select t.titre from titres t inner join selections s on s.tid=t.tid where s.did="$did" and s.cid=$cid and s.choice=1;
#+END_SRC
```

I get

- ("Airbnb, la fÃªte est-elle vraiment finie ?" "" "")
- ("Apprendre Ã  manager une Ã©quipe en coachant des moutons" "" "")
- ("Â« StupÃ©fiant ! Â» met Ã  nu le mystÃ¨re Houellebecq" "" "")

when I cast titre to binary and convert to utf8...

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql coding: utf-8-with-signature :results list :var did='2019-03-10' cid=77
  select trim(convert(cast(t.titre as binary) using utf8)) as titre from titres t inner join selections s on s.tid=t.tid where s.did="$did" and s.cid=$cid and s.choice=1;
#+END_SRC
```

I get

- ("Airbnb, la fête est-elle vraiment finie ?" "" "")
- ("Apprendre à manager une équipe en coachant des moutons" "" "")
- ("« Stupéfiant ! » met à nu le mystère Houellebecq" "" "")

which is nice and I can live with it... but I want the output without the quotes and the parentheses, so I added **org** to the list of results parameters

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql coding: utf-8-with-signature :results list org :var did='2019-03-10' cid=77
  select trim(convert(cast(t.titre as binary) using utf8)) as titre from titres t inner join selections s on s.tid=t.tid where s.did="$did" and s.cid=$cid and s.choice=1;
#+END_SRC
```

and I get

- Airbnb, la f\303\252 est-elle vraiment finie ?

but when I copied the previous sentence into the emacs.stackexchange.com text input it reads like it should, i.e.

- Airbnb, la fête est-elle vraiment finie ?

the buffer coding system (shown in the lower left corner of the emacs window) says (multi-byte) utf-8-unix.

How can I get the output to print in a human-readable way?

**Update**
I added

```
 #+name: echo_me
 #+BEGIN_SRC sh :var data="" :results output
   echo "$data"
 #+END_SRC
```

and added a :post option to the src block

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql coding: utf-8-with-signature :results list org :var did='2019-03-10' cid=77  :post echo_me(data=*this*)
```

now it works fine, but before the output is generated Emacs asks me to pick a coding system (raw), since utf-8-unix does not contain the accented characters. I wonder whether there is a better solution, and I'd like to understand what is happening.

Comment: "...since utf-8-unix does not contain the accented characters." : I don't believe that is true. Is there a way to simulate what's happening without the database? It would at least make it easier for others to test. If you don't get an answer here, post it on the [help-gnu-emacs](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/help-gnu-emacs) mailing list.

Comment: Thanks Nick. When I write "utf-8-unix does not contain the accented characters" I am only reporting what emacs tells me. Here is the the beginning of the message from the \*Warning\* buffer: These default coding systems were tried to encode text in the buffer ‘\*temp\*’:
  (utf-8-unix (20 . 4194243) (21 . 4194218) (61 . 4194243) (62
  . 4194208) (76 . 4194243) (77 . 4194217) (108 . 4194242) (109
  . 4194219) (115 . 4194243) (116 . 4194217) (125 . 4194242))
However, each of them encountered characters it couldn’t encode:
  utf-8-unix cannot encode these:

Comment: Emacs then suggests to use 'raw-text' encoding. I copied the \*temp\* buffer to a file, and tried to reproduce the behavior with the file which is encoded in raw-text, but the shell src block outputs the results without a problem. I think the only way to reproduce the problem would be to provide code to make a temporary mysql table and then use a query on that.

Comment: I removed the post command and saved the file and re-opened it. The "raw-text" output appears fine in the re-opened file.